# How to add proxy support to mechanicalsoup?

Tags: python, mechanicalsoup

```
import mechanicalsoup

proxies = {
    "http": "socks5://127.0.0.1:49260",
    "https": "socks5://127.0.0.1:49260"
}
url = 'https://whatismyip.com/'
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

browser.session.proxies = proxies   # This seem can't work

page = browser.open(url)  #, verify=False
print(page)
print(page.text)
```

I try to add proxy to my webbot, by using mechanicalsoup, but this can't work, and the official document didn't mention this,  Where's a working demo about this? Thank you

Comment: What is the error saying?

Comment: No error output, just not show the proxy address, it show my real address.

Comment: MechanicalSoup does nothing for proxies, but relies on requests which does support it. Assigning a dict to `session.proxies` is supposed to work [according to the doc](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/api/#requests.Session.proxies), or you can build your own session object passing a `proxies` argument, and then pass this session object to [`mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()`'s constructor](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mechanicalsoup.html#mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser). Setting `$http_proxy` and similar environment variables is supposed to work too.